# Deriving 68% confidence level for each parameter after MCMC

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, statistical-inference, markov-process, descriptive-statistics

I used the MCMC package https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-mcmc to find the best parameters for model of Massive Gravity. Now I need to find the confidence 68% for each of those parameters and have no idea how to proceed. This is my first time doing anything like this. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1613v1.pdf I'm trying to reproduce the confidence levels in this paper which are in results section. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I have not used this particular package, but here is the general method for MCMC confidence intervals: First, for each parameter, look at a history plot of its simulated values to make sure the chain in 'mixing well', that is fluctuating among reasonable values, not getting stuck at exactly the same value. Second, look at its 'trace' (cumulative average of values) to see that it is converging to a particular value. Third, find a reasonable 'burn in' point after which the trace is relatively stable. Then to find a 68%CI take the 16th and 84th percentiles of its distribution after burn in.